# How to add facility configuration in Castle Windsor v3+ using code?

Tags: inversion-of-control, castle-windsor, ioc-container, windsor-facilities

In Castle Windsor v3+ the `IWindsorContainer.AddFacility<T>(string idlnConfiguration)` method has been deprecated. In the old version you could use this method to add dynamic configuration by calling `IConfigurationStore.AddFacilityConfiguration(string key, IConfiguration config)` where "idlnConfiguration" and "key" were the same in the calls.

For example:

```
store.AddFacilityConfiguration("quartzNet", facilityConfig);
container.AddFacility<QuartzFacility>("quartzNet");
```

What is the recommended way of doing this in Windsor 3? The message on the ObsoleteAttribute points at using `container.AddFacility<T>()` instead, but I can't see how.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the recommended way is to use

```
container.AddFacility<SomeFacility>(f => f.Configure("me").Here());
```

obviously the facility has to support this.

Comment: Thanks, that what I thought it was for. :) I suppose the ObsoleteAttribute message should point to that method instead to avoid confusion.

Comment: Sure :) https://github.com/castleproject/Windsor/pull/10 I see you already closed it ;)

Comment: @KrzysztofKozmi,
what should be the implementation for Configure and Here in facility?
I am stuck with something similar after NHibernate, Castle upgrade..
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26094161/castle-facilities-nhibernateintegration-for-nhibernate-4-0