# Castle Facilities NHibernateIntegration for NHibernate 4.0

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, castle-windsor, castle

I downloaded the source for NHibernateIntegration from (https://github.com/mahara/Castle.Facilities.NHibernateIntegration)

I added reference for Castle.Core (3.3.0.0), Castle.Services.Transaction (3.3.0.0), Castle.Windsor (3.3.0.0), NHibernate (4.0.0.4000) and I built the application to generate the Castle.Facilities.NHibernateIntegration.dll

But after the upgrading NHibernateIntegration.dll in my application I am getting the following error,

**An ISessionFactory component was not mapped for the specified alias: AliasName**

Comment: I have updated all the castle dlls from 2.5 to 3.3 and NHibernate dlls from 3.1 to 4.0
I am not sure which is creating this problem

Comment: Where are you getting the error?

Comment: @AndrewWhitaker,
I get this whenever I try to open session with SessionManager passing the alias to OpenSession method.

Answer (score 0):

Try to update NullSafeGet(IDataReader rs, string name) code 

 NHibernate.Type.NullSafeGet to

```
public virtual object NullSafeGet(IDataReader rs, string name)
    {
        int index = 0;

        try
        {
            name = name.ToUpperInvariant();
            index = rs.GetOrdinal(name);

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception(string.Format("{0} Not Found", name));
        }
```

...
}

Comment: I dont have source code for NHibernate..I am using the dll for 4.0, I also tried to extend the Type class of NHibernate..couldnot find NullSafeGet.